# Is the derivative of the logarithm map isometric？

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$, $p,q\in \mathcal{M}$, $\log_p:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow T_p\mathcal{M}$ denote the logarithm maps. Defining its derivative:
$$d[\log_pq]:T_q\mathcal{M} \rightarrow T_p \mathcal{M}$$
I want to know whether the derivative of the logarithm map is isometric? i.e.,
$$\|d[\log_pq] (\xi)\|_p = \|\xi\|_q,~~ \forall \xi \in T_q \mathcal{M}$$
Or under what conditions can it be established?

In addition, what connection between parallel transport and derivative of the logarithm map?

Comment: Essentially equivalent to this question on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317539/differentiating-riemannian-logarithmic-map

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition is that the metric on the image of $\exp_p(T_pM)$ is flat.